# "File format is not supported" while multi threading a list of pdf files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-camelot

I am teaching myself the basics of threading in python and am stuck.
I want the script to apply a function to a list of pdfs. This function is simply supposed to count the number of tables in each pdf file and then return a combined list of how many tables each file has.

Right now, I am getting a error stating that my “file format is not supported”. As far as I can tell each path in the list is a full path that ends with .pdf. I don’t know what I am doing wrong?

I have stripped down the code to the salient points and have included my code below

```
import camelot
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
import glob
import os


#get a list of all the pdf paths in the directory I am interested in
pdfs = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\josiahh\Desktop\threading_learning')]

#format each path to have the r letter in front of it
rpdfs = ["r'" + pdf + "'" for pdf in pdfs]

#function that counts each table in the pdf. THIS IS WHERE SOMETHING IS WRONG...I THINK
listoflengths = []
def len_table5(filepath):    
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(filepath, pages = '1-end',flavor='stream')
    tablelength = len(tables)
    listoflengths.append(tablelength)

#threading code
pool = ThreadPool(5) 
results = pool.map(len_table5, rpdfs)
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can clarify anything

EDIT:
Traceback when using r's in front of the file names

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-d38bdf75c567> in <module>
      1 
      2 pool = ThreadPool(5)
----> 3 results = pool.map(len_table5, rpdfs)
      4 pool.close()
      5 pool.join()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    286         in a list that is returned.
    287         '''
--> 288         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    289 
    290     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    668             return self._value
    669         else:
--> 670             raise self._value
    671 
    672     def _set(self, i, obj):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    117         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    118         try:
--> 119             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    120         except Exception as e:
    121             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in mapstar(args)
     42 
     43 def mapstar(args):
---> 44     return list(map(*args))
     45 
     46 def starmapstar(args):

<ipython-input-54-025080eb0d6f> in len_table5(filepath)
      1 listoflengths = []
      2 def len_table5(filepath):
----> 3     tables = camelot.read_pdf(filepath, pages = '1-end',flavor='stream')
      4     tablelength = len(tables)
      5     listoflengths.append(tablelength)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py in read_pdf(filepath, pages, password, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    101 
    102         validate_input(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
--> 103         p = PDFHandler(filepath, pages=pages, password=password)
    104         kwargs = remove_extra(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
    105         tables = p.parse(flavor=flavor, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py in __init__(self, filepath, pages, password)
     33         self.filepath = filepath
     34         if not filepath.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
---> 35             raise NotImplementedError("File format not supported")
     36 
     37         if password is None:

NotImplementedError: File format not supported
```

Traceback when not using rs in the file path

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-07744a46a83f> in <module>
      1 
      2 pool = ThreadPool(5)
----> 3 results = pool.map(len_table5, pdfs)
      4 pool.close()
      5 pool.join()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    286         in a list that is returned.
    287         '''
--> 288         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    289 
    290     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    668             return self._value
    669         else:
--> 670             raise self._value
    671 
    672     def _set(self, i, obj):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    117         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    118         try:
--> 119             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    120         except Exception as e:
    121             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in mapstar(args)
     42 
     43 def mapstar(args):
---> 44     return list(map(*args))
     45 
     46 def starmapstar(args):

<ipython-input-58-e6499958826d> in len_table5(filepath)
     14 listoflengths = []
     15 def len_table5(filepath):
---> 16     tables = camelot.read_pdf(filepath, pages = '1-end',flavor='stream')
     17     tablelength = len(tables)
     18     listoflengths.append(tablelength)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py in read_pdf(filepath, pages, password, flavor, suppress_stdout, layout_kwargs, **kwargs)
    101 
    102         validate_input(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
--> 103         p = PDFHandler(filepath, pages=pages, password=password)
    104         kwargs = remove_extra(kwargs, flavor=flavor)
    105         tables = p.parse(flavor=flavor, suppress_stdout=suppress_stdout,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py in __init__(self, filepath, pages, password)
     41             if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
     42                 self.password = self.password.encode('ascii')
---> 43         self.pages = self._get_pages(self.filepath, pages)
     44 
     45     def _get_pages(self, filepath, pages):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py in _get_pages(self, filepath, pages)
     64             page_numbers.append({'start': 1, 'end': 1})
     65         else:
---> 66             infile = PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb'), strict=False)
     67             if infile.isEncrypted:
     68                 infile.decrypt(self.password)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\josiahh\\camelot - Copy (2) - Copy.pdf'
```

Comment: "#format each path to have the r letter in front of it" I think that's your issue. Drop that lost comp and pass the list of file paths to your function without that modification

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the reply. I have tried to feed the pdfs straight into the function without adding the r and it fails. I have atleast had a little success when implelemting the rs

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: @roganjosh I have edited the post and included both tracebacks

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider:

1. Do not hardcode path strings, it's not flexible and the most likely
   won't work on different machines.
2. `os.listdir()` just returns filenames in the folder, so `os.path.abspath()` won't give you the correct result.
3. Not sure about adding prefixes to filenames, do you really need this?

The corrected version would be:

```
import os
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

import camelot

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname((os.path.abspath(__file__)))

FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "threading_learning")

pdfs = [os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(FOLDER_PATH)]

listoflengths = []


def len_table5(filepath):
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(filepath, pages='1-end', flavor='stream')
    tablelength = len(tables)
    listoflengths.append(tablelength)


# threading code
pool = ThreadPool(5)
results = pool.map(len_table5, pdfs)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print(listoflengths)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try and answer this, just incase someone has a similar problem. What I found, is that the section that filters for pdfs was not implemented properly. You need a filter to make sure that the files returned are all pdfs.

So change:

```
pdfs = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\josiahh\Desktop\threading_learning')]
```

to this:

```
pdfs = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\josiahh\Desktop\threading_learning') if x.endswith(".pdf")]
```

You will notice that I have added if x.endswith(".pdf"), to only return the pdf files.

Please try this and let me know it works for you.
The original error stated that `NotImplementedError: File format not supported.`  That means it is passing files that are not pdf.